# HTML Table rendering algorithms, recommended reading?

Tags: html, algorithm

I was wondering how modern browsers render html tables, for example how they figure out the exact size of the cells. After googling a bit, all I found was an [RFC from 1996](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1942.txt), but nothing new. Since I also read that html 5 specifies the parsing algorithm, so I thought maybe the algorithm for determinating the layout is also specified or at least it is described how a possible algorithm should work. Just looking at the code of open source browsers would probably be very time consuming and therefore rather not an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifically regarding tables: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout

The full spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cover.html#minitoc

Comment: There doesn't seem to be more litereature available. Thx for the link.

Answer (score 12):

Not specific to HTML, but the paper [**The Table Layout Problem**](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.3.1460&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Richard J. Anderson, Sumeet Sobti) analyzes laying out a table, e.g. minimum height for fixed width and other problems.

It concludes that the problem is NP-complete and suggests a number of heuristics.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of math ;) I am surprised that I still get good answers for a question I asked in 2012, thanks for contributing!